# Svelte throwing 500 errors inconsistently

Tags: svelte

I am using Svelte for the first time. I am on Node 18 and generated an app using `svelte@latest` (using the "skeleton" template). I didn't make any changes except installing the `p5` library and changing the `+page.svelte` to as follows:

```
<script>
import p5 from "p5";
const p5Setup = (pfive) => {
  pfive.setup = function() {
    pfive.createCanvas(700, 410);
  };

  pfive.draw = function() {
    pfive.background(0);
    pfive.fill(255);
    pfive.rect(100, 100, 50, 50);
  };
};

new p5(p5Setup)

</script>

<h1>Welcome to SvelteKit</h1>
<p>Visit <a href="https://kit.svelte.dev">kit.svelte.dev</a> to read the documentation</p>
```

Here's what happens. When I load the page, I get a 500 error in the browser, and in console it shows:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default')
    at +page.svelte:15:4
    at Object.$$render (/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.mjs:1892:22)
    at Object.default (root.svelte:42:40)
    at eval (/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/components/layout.svelte:8:41)
    at Object.$$render (/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.mjs:1892:22)
    at root.svelte:41:39
    at $$render (/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.mjs:1892:22)
    at Object.render (/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.mjs:1900:26)
    at Module.render_response (/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/page/render.js:138:29)
    at async Module.render_page (/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/page/index.js:308:10)
```

When I comment out the line `new p5(p5Setup)` it works. Then when I uncomment it, it works. But as soon as I add anything else to the script (e.g. `var foo = "bar"`) it goes to the 500 error again.

I am about to give up on Svelte since this first experience has been horrible. I really wanted to give it a fair try, and am hoping I'm just missing something and the development process isn't this buggy in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have a race condition of some kind. Sometimes two different things finish in the correct order, and it works. Sometimes they don't finish in the correct order, and then it crashes. So most likely the problem is that you use the `p5` library wrong in Svelte, and not Svelte itself.

I don't know the `p5` library, but looking at your code, I'm guessing it's supposed to draw some stuff on a Canvas, that is created and inserted into the DOM by the `p5` library. I'm guessing this is (somehow) related to the problem with the potential race condition you are experiencing. When using a framework, you need to do things the way the framework is supposed to work. No framework is designed to work automatically with all different libraries out there that are designed to do "global things" on their own.

So try to:

1. In your Svelte component, insert a `<div>`, and add a custom [action](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/actions) to it
2. In the custom action, write your `p5` code, and pass the `div` object as the second argument to [the `p5()` constructor](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/p5)

Hopefully that will fix your problem. Otherwise the problem might be that `p5` pollutes the global scope, and ruins Svelte that way.

Comment: Thanks so much, you were totally right here